# How do display PDF or Large amount of text in Android application with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, textview, xamarin.android

I am building an android app with Xamarin.android. I am almost done with what I need except one concept I am not sure how to approach. I have a UI that needs to display a waiver for the user to sign. I have the signature pad and everything but I am not sure what to use to display the waiver. I am sure I will need to incorporate a scroll-view for it but I don't know what to use to display the test. Textview doesn't seem quite right. The Waiver is in PDF format but I am able to copy all the text out of it also. Any Insight on How I should go about this? I have to be able to have the sign box fit underneath it also. 
Thanks!
P.S. I am fairly new to Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

Since you're developing a xamarin.android project, standard methods for displaying PDF vis Java code should also work via Xamarin.Android.

It means, you can try to use [PdfRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html) in your xamarin.android project to parse and show PDF files.

Or since you're able to copy all the text, you can simply use `TextView` for displaying blocks of text.

Method 1: Use `TextView` itself, set `android:scrollbars="vertical"` and `android:singleLine="false"` for example:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/waiver_content_text_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="30dp"
      android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"
      android:singleLine="false"
      android:text="this is content, blablabla..." />
</LinearLayout>
```

code behind:

```cs
public class Waiver_Fragment : Fragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.WaiverFragment, container, false);
        TextView content = (TextView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.waiver_content_text_view);
        content.MovementMethod = new Android.Text.Method.ScrollingMovementMethod();
        return view;
    }
}
```

Method 2: Put `TextView` inside of a `ScrollView`, this method doesn't require code behind for handling scroll method like the method above, for example:

```xml
<ScrollView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/news_item_content_text_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="30dp"
      android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
      android:text="this is content, blablabla..." />
</ScrollView>
```

If you're using xamarin.forms for cross-platform application development, you can also refer to [Display a Local PDF File in a WebView](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/). This recipe shows how to display a local PDF file in a WebView control on each platform.

Answer (score -1):

Use a webview to display the pdf